# Capture null on pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, null

On regular non-spark Jupyter Notebook, I write

```
for y in df.columns:
    df["mflag"]= df["y"].isnull()
```

It shows True = 704.  False = 24583. The count I know is correct.

Now the same source CSV file is read into Pyspark df. The variable Y is double (nullable=True). This is also correct because y is a ratio variable.

I write below to try to replicate what I did on Jupyter notebook, creating a mflag that separates 704 null from the 24583 not null.

```
df = df.withColumn('mflag', when(df['y'].isNull,"0").when(df['y'].isNotNull, "1").otherwise("1"))
```

It does not create error. But in the df, it produces 9 instances of mflag: string (nullable=false). If I use 1 instead of "1", it produces 9 integer... Useless because mflg cannot be called upon later. Obviously I only need 1 mflag. What is wrong? Jia

Comment: it should be `isNull()` and `isNotNull()` with parantheses. And you can remove the second `when` as this case is already covered by `otherwise`.

Comment: This works. I count on () to fill up automatically. When it does not, i forgot to pay attention. Now mflag is not capturing null. That is another subject. Thanks. I want to give your answer a thumb up as solution, cannot find where to push it. Let me know.